# How does Azure Blob Store treat files ending in .gz?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a file named `notactuallygunzipped.gz`that is a plain text file that happens to end in `.gz` and is NOT actually gunzipped that looks like so:

```
1 foo bar
2 fizz buzz
```

I upload it to Azure like so:

```
az storage blob upload \
  --container-name testroot \
  --file notactuallygunzipped.gz \
  --name "gunzip/notactuallygunzipped.gz"
```

I then use the Azure Go SDK to [fetch the blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/storage/blob.go#L206). I'd expect to get back something like `1 foo bar` or whatever in byte format, but instead I'm

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x9d\xfa-Y\x00\x03notactuallygunzipped\x003TH\xcb\xcfWHJ,\xe22RH\xca\xccKWH\xca\xcfK\xe7\x02\x00\xa5\x00\xef\x1e\x16\x00\x00\x00
```

If I rename the file to something like `plaindata.txt` it works fine and I get what I expect:

```
'1 foo bar\n2 fizz buzz\n'
```

Does Azure do something wonky? Either automatic compression or something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not matter with Azure. The file `notactuallygunzipped.gz` you uploaded is a gzip compressed file. You can read it via `less` command which default supports decompress gzip format that looks like plain text, but it's binary format if using `cat`. So you need to decompress the bytes of the blob downloaded from Azure Blob Storage via go package `compress/gzip`.

As reference, here is my sample code using Go for reading gzip file from Azure Blob Storage.

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-storage-go"
)

func main() {
    accountName := "<your-account-name>"
    accountKey := "<your-account-key>"
    client, _ := storage.NewBasicClient(accountName, accountKey)
    blobClient := client.GetBlobService()
    containerName := "mycontainer"
    container := blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName)
    flag, _ := container.CreateIfNotExists(nil)
    fmt.Println(flag)
    blobName := "notactuallygunzipped.gz"
    blob := container.GetBlobReference(blobName)
    readCloser, _ := blob.Get(nil)
    defer readCloser.Close()
    zr, _ := gzip.NewReader(readCloser)
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(zr)
    fmt.Printf("%s", content)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually decompress files that way, but in my case I'm uploading a plain text file that has the `.gz` extension - I never actually compress it (see my edits)

Comment: @ClicquottheDog I tried to upload a text file named `notactuallygunzipped.gz` as same as yours via `az` cli tool, and downloaded it via my golang program without `gzip`. That show pure & origin text content without any binary byte format. So I'm sure Azure Blob Storage and `az` tool would not change your file. Meanwhile, I confirmed your file has been compressed that is according to your byte format content from blob which includes a file name header information, not just due to the `.gz` extension.

Comment: turns out my editor was autocompressing the file - today I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

> BLOB - **Binary** Large OBject

The content or file extension does not matter. From Azure [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs):

> Azure Blob storage is a service that stores unstructured data in the
>   cloud as objects/blobs. Blob storage can store any type of text or
>   binary data, such as a document, media file, or application installer.
>   Blob storage is also referred to as object storage